# Azure Search min max values

Tags: azure, faceted-search, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index that is populated with Products. Each product has price field. I want to implement facet navigation on categories pages and i want my users to be able to search for products within a price range. At the same time, I want them to know what the minimum and maximum product price is across products in selected category. As i know Azure Search  does not support min/max values in responses. So i am looking for some work around. I think that i can mark my price field as facetable and get min and max value from facet result, but default facet results count is 10, and if i understand correctly to get all prices from facet result i need to set count to Int.Max or something. That does not sound nice.

So what is the best solution to get min and max product price in specific category?

Answer (score 1):

More direct approach to get the min and max product prices would be using $filter, $orderBy and $top in a Search request.

For example,

https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/products/docs?search=*&$filter=productName eq 'Toys'&$orderBy=price asc&$top=1.

You will need to parse the price in the response.

The approach using facet would be more expensive and, as you said, can only get you an approximation because boundaries of each facet is from pre-configured range.

Nate